# How can I grab a value only if all keys in the path exist?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have the `Values.yaml` file below:

```yaml
global:
  metadata:
    annotations:
      test: ABC
```

And I want to use it inside a template:

```yaml
...
{{- if .Values.global.metadata }}
annotations:
  {{- .Values.global.metadata.annotations | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
{{- end }}
...
```

But, I want to make it so that if I don't specify the `.Values.global`, it won't error if I don't have any of these keys. The only way I could think of:

```yaml
{{- if .Values.global }}
{{- if .Values.global.metadata }}
annotations:
  {{- .Values.global.metadata.annotations | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
...
```

When it comes to other examples, like `.Values.a.b.c.d`, it becomes painful to keep doing it this way.

Is there any better solution that won't need several nested `if` statements?

Answer (score 1):

When I need to do this, I set a variable for each level of the values hierarchy.  You can use the [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) function to provide a value if some level isn't present, combined with the [`dict`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dict) function to create an empty map.

```yaml
{{- $global := .Values.global | default dict }}
{{- $metadata := $global.metadata | default dict }}
{{- with $metadata.annotations }}
annotations:
{{ . | toYaml | indent 2 }}
{{- end }}
```

Flattening the layout of your values file can help reduce the amount of this setup you need.  `.Values.global` is special, but beyond that a shallower hierarchy will be easier to traverse than a deeper one.